# SSMS - auto complete Parameters (intellisense)

Tags: t-sql, ssms

I already got used to intellisense failing (cant really blame it, sql is weird per design) and I know I can "resfresh" it with (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) - which sometimes even works.

What makes me mad is the "parameters peek" when I start writing a funktion call. It lists all parameters and highlights (bold) the parameter that is expected at that position.

As soon as something goes "wrong" the "parameter peek" disappears and never shows itself again. (i.e. dbo.SomeFunc(@val1 int , @val2 int)  ... start writing "dbo.SomeFunc " and the "peek" will show up. Now insert "-1" instead of "1" and see it fail.)

This drives me crazy, is there a way to bring it up again? (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> or so?)

I dont know what that "parameter peek" is called and if it is part of intellisense or not. If its not possible to show it again, it would be nice to deactivate without the other intellisense funktions. I tend to rely on it when it pops up and go mad when it disappers again. >:(

SSMS v17.3 (14.0.17199.0)

Thanks in advance for any hint
Jan

Comment: Well, SSMS is kinda bad at it. You would think Microsoft would do a better job since visual studio proves they can do it much, much better. I suspect that without using a 3rd party add-in (like SQL Prompt, which is **not** free), you'll just have to get used to it.

Answer (score 0):

Retyping the opening parentheses `(` for the parameters does the trick for me in SSMS 2017.6

Comment: Good one, but in my case Parentheses are not firing the peek at all, only works with "space". (At the moment I don't know for sure when (t)sql requires parentheses and when they are not allowed. .. as confusing as VBA), but thx for the hint! =)